# Iterate through widgets by names

Tags: loops

I have some entries Tkinter widget named like this :

Entry_name_1
Entry_name_2
Entry_name_3
...
Entry_name_25

How do i iterate through the 25 Entries in a loop ?

I'm looking for something like
Entry_name_[str(i)] but it's not working.

The purpose is to populate many ENTRIES widgets with an excel sheet datas.

Here is my code :

```
import openpyxl
# opening the source excel file
filename = "excel_templates/ex.xlsx"
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]


for i in range(5, 25):
    # reading cell value from source excel file
    c = ws1.cell(row=i, column=1)
    # writing the read value to destination
    Entry_name_[str(i)].insert(0,c)
```

Comment: You simply add those into a list and iterate through the list. You probably dont need to make 25 entries manually too, show the code for creation of entries please

Comment: How about a python tag?